# I have each endpoint is protected by spring security+ filter, which from the request header checks the token and passes the request

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket

I have each endpoint is protected by spring security+ filter, which from the request header checks the token and passes the request, I can not connect to the endpoint ws because when sending a request to connect to the socket, the filter does not pass it, because it does not have a header with a token, I read the API WebSocket does not provide the ability to send requests with headers, only a parameter, can anyone tell me how to be?

I was thinking of creating a separate filter for websockets.